# error while using aggregation $in operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using below aggregation

```
Model.aggregate([
  { $project: { isLike: { $in: [id, "$isLike"] }}}
])
```

Getting below error

```
$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing
```

Kindly help why I am getting the above error

Comment: It means that `isLike` is not an array in *"some"* of your documents. Use `{ $in: [ id, { $ifNull: [ "$isLike", [] ] } ] }` or `{ $in: [ id, { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$isLike" }, then: "$isLike", else: [] } } ] }` just in case a field is there but is something other than an array. But really this is using mongoose, so it should be expected your schema defines this as an array. If you have documents where this is not an array, you probably should clean your data. And if it's not meant to be an array at all, then `$in` is not the right operator here.

Comment: Got it thank you @NeilLunn and Anthony